# Prove that there is only one $f$ using the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

*So the exercise goes like this:*
**Problem**

> (a)Prove that the there is a $f:[0,1]$ that satisfies the following condition:
> $$ f(x)=\cos(x)+ \int^x_0{f(y)e^{-y}dy}\text{ for } x\epsilon[0,1] $$
> **Hint:Use the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for Ordinary Differential Equations**
>
> Why the solution of $f$ must be defined in the range of $[0,1]$?

---

So my proof goes like this:
In order to use the theorem mentioned earlier we have to write the given equation as a differential equation.So we have the following:
$$f'(x)=-\sin(x)+f(x)\cdot e^{-x}$$
Moreover,
$$f'(x) \text{ and } \frac {\partial df } {\partial y} \text{are both continious in a rectangle:} [0,1] \times [-M,M], M>0$$
So by the theorem of existence and uniquess for ordinary differential
equations there is a $f$ that satisfies the differential equation and the initial condition ($f(0)=1$) in some interval $I$ containing $0$.

---

**My questiions:**
1.Is their any simplier proof?
2.What i should write as answer for the (b)?What i mean is there any solid proof like in the part (a)?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: There is something missing, usually function declarations $f:D\to R$ specify a domain $D$ and a range $R$. You have only one. What is the connection of $g$ to the task? The derivative of the equation is $f'(x)=-\sin x+e^{-x}f(x)$. What do you know about the existence of solutions here? One could also start with $F(x)=\int_0^xe^{-y}f(y)dy$ to get $F'(x)=e^{-x}(\cos x+F(x))$. There might be domain restrictions in the proof construction, the solution itself has no restrictions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann i think now i got it for the first one but one the second part of the questuion i can not see the possible restrictions on the domain

Comment: You have a linear DE with continuous coefficients. This gives already solutions with unconstrained domains.